# Remove protective coating quickly

Tags: cabinets

I have a contract to install a lot of kitchens. I have had to deal with protective film on doors before but I just picked at it, it takes forever to remove. I tried a heat gun this time but it wasn’t much faster. Does anyone have any idea on how to quickly remove this type of film?

[image]

Comment: ...you should have factored the time to remove into your bid on the contract. Might try grabbing it with tape. Should come off as one piece if you find the right angle and speed to pull at, but if the cabinets have been stored improperly or the material is defective, you might have the sort of problems where it only comes off in small pieces. For speed, a slower pull may be faster at the end result than a quick tear.

Comment: Find starting at a corner with a slow steady pull sideways and down/up will work most times.

Comment: Push back on the supplier to provide better protective coatings that aren't so time-consuming.

Comment: Generally speaking, once you get an edge up, it'll just pull right off... Maybe contact the manufacturer to see if they have a recommended way if you're struggling with it?

Comment: @ecnerwal money isn’t the issue but it takes longer to peel this off than it does to install the kitchen.

Comment: Time is money if you are doing the work and getting paid a fixed price. If you get paid by the hour, time taken is money you get paid.

Comment: @ecnerwal I understand the money/time function very well I make enough to try to peel this off with my toenails blindfolded if I wanted the problem is I dont have time at this rate in the project even if I paid more people to do it which is why I’m asking for recommendations ...

Comment: @freeman yeah I had that experience with a different film that was blue it would peel pretty well this stuff seems to break off.

Comment: Hire a squad of teenagers? This isn't a home improvement question.

Comment: @isherwood it’s hard to hire anyone in Canada right now since the gov is paying folks to stay at home

Comment: Try a spray bottle filled with a mild detergent/water solution... Spray as you pull, bet that stuff comes right off.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not about home improvement.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a pressing reason you can't leave it in place for the new occupant to remove?

Many times things like this have a label saying something like "Remove film before use". Perhaps print up a few sheets of stickers that say "Remove protective film before use" and put one on each door.

If I was the new owner of the kitchen I wouldn't feel this is too much of a burden on me, and I might even be pleased that I get all of the "newness" of the appliance.

Comment: This is a great idea for turning a burden into a benefit.  Your kitchen is still in the wrapper!

Comment: I have seen this done (instructed not to remove plastic unless it's internal) and offered to the customer as a feature.  On that project OPs doors would have meant removing any internal plastic and just enough that the knobs handles and hinges aren't pinning the plastic.

Comment: I don’t remove the entire film but I have to remove enough so that the film won’t be under the handle, the handles are large so I have to peel a good amount.

Answer (score 3):

Since it sounds like the film is disintegrating when you try to peel it:

Tape the whole surface, peel the tape (and film) off. You'll need a tape with an adhesive that's more stubborn that the film-to-cabinet bond. I'd probably start with plain old packing tape - fairly strong, usually has good adhesive, inexpensive, can be had wide. But you may need to experiment to find the best tape for the job.

Using a roller on the tape after application and before attempting to peel may help to achieve a better/more uniform bond to the film.

Comment: Thank you I’m going to pick up a few different rolls and do some experiments

Answer (score 0):

No one mentioned Goof Off or similar products, which got most of it off on mine. Tape did not work for me. I am currently having trouble getting the film off the edges and curved areas of the cabinet door. Heating it with a blow dryer may loosen/take off the whole white coating, so that is no good. I have been working on mine in the sun, with Goof Off, a plactic scraper and a tweezer. It has been real time consuming and annoying.
For the record, mine was just 1 door that the film removal was missed on, and went unnoticed for many years! Too long to report it to the installer. One day I noticed it had become yellowed compared to the twin door next to it. Upon further review, I could see the clear film pulling away in a few spots. It HAD to go in order to match the rest, or replace them all! No thanks!

Comment: It doesn't sound like Goof Off is working all that well since you've heated, applied GO and still have to scrape and tweeze to get the plastic off...